# Codebuild failed with docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, codebuild

I would like to make container image with codebuild, but this error occurs.

Dose it mean docker runtime is not installed correctly...?

also I don't understand the `Setting HTTP client timeout to higher timeout for S3 source` means, why it has to access to `S3`?

I am using Ubuntu `aws/codebuild/standard:5.0`

How can I fix this?

```
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:50.314922 Running on CodeBuild On-demand
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:50.314949 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:50.516418 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:51.928318 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:51.929434 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src2192185452/src
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:51.929900 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src2192185452/src/buildspec_dev.yml
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:51.931657 Setting HTTP client timeout to higher timeout for S3 source
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:51.931749 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:51.975059 Setting HTTP client timeout to higher timeout for S3 source
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:52.048809 Setting HTTP client timeout to higher timeout for S3 source
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:52.292731 Selecting 'docker' runtime version '18' based on manual selections...
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:52.297790 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/03/19 11:33:52.297815 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Unknown runtime named 'docker'. This build image has the following runtimes: dotnet, golang, java, nodejs, php, python, ruby
```

my `buildspec.yml` is like this

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
    commands:
      - echo install step...
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo logging in to AWS ECR...
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ap-northeast-1)
      - echo Logging in to Docker Hub...
      - echo $DOCKERHUB_PASS | docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_USER --password-stdin
  build:
    commands:
      - echo build Docker image on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t 678100228133.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev-aiff:latest -f Dockerfile.django.dev.fargate .

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo build Docker image complete `date`
      - echo push latest Docker images to ECR...
      - docker push 678100228133.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev-aiff:latest

env:
  secrets-manager:
    DOCKERHUB_USER: arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-northeast-1:678100228133:secret:docker_login-TBFA5B:username
    DOCKERHUB_PASS: arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-northeast-1:678100228133:secret:docker_login-TBFA5B:password
```

Comment: Docker is provided, but not available as "runtime". Remove it from `runtime-versions` and go on. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html